# Popup in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, alert, popupwindow

I want to show a popup with media element as one control.
When user clicks on the button, then I have to show this popup. And when user clicks on the back button of the device then the popup should be closed.

Please help me how to do this in windows phone 8 application.

Answer (score 9):

**Popup with MediaElement** (view is name of `PhoneApplicationPage`)

```
<Popup
    x:Name="popup">

    <Grid
        Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}"
        Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=view}"
        Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=view}">

        <MediaElement />

    </Grid>

</Popup>
```

**Application Bar**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar>

        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton
            Click="ShowPopup"
            IconUri="/Icons/show.png"
            Text="show" />

    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.popup.IsOpen)
    {
        this.popup.IsOpen = false; 
        e.Cancel = true;
    }

    base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
}


private void ShowPopup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.popup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a `Popup` control & have to set your media element as it's `Child` Property.And to handle Back Key press use OnBackKeyPress overriden event.
  Please see below sample.

```
    private Popup _popup;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid g=new Grid {Height = 400,Width = 480,Background =new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green)};
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle
            {
                Height = 50,
                Width=50,
                Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
            };
        g.Children.Add(r);
        _popup = new Popup()
           {
               Height = 400,
               Width = 480,
               IsOpen = true,
               Child = g
           };          
    }

    protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_popup != null)
        {
            if (_popup.IsOpen)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                _popup.IsOpen = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you press back key, You should check is popup open? If popup open then prevent the back key action. So override **`OnBackKeyPress()`** like this:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.popup.IsOpen)
    {
        this.popup.IsOpen = false; 
        e.Cancel = true;
    }

    base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
}
```