# How to change PopupMenu's background?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

Is it possible to customize PopupMenu's background. PopupMenu object hasn't that property.

```
var popupMenu = new PopupMenu();
```

Comment: @Sajeetharan, windows-8.1 app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322449/popup-in-windows-phone-8

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, PopupMenu does not accept styling.

Maybe you can use Flyouts which is Microsoft's recommended way of handling Tap events on UI:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465341.aspx

Taken from the link:

*A flyout is a lightweight popup that is used to temporarily show UI that is related to what the user is currently doing. It can be used to show a menu, reveal a hidden control, show more details about an item, or ask the user to confirm an action. You should only show a flyout in response to a user tap or click. A flyout is always dismissed when the user taps outside of it.*

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you aren't using a WPF Popup object. In xaml, assign a panel that possesses the Background property and set that:

```
<Popup>
    <Grid Background="Green" />
</Popup>
```

Comment: I use PopupMenu object, not a Popup object. I can't set a Child for PopupMenu.